# ASP.Net FormsAuthentication Rememberme

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using forms authentication in a web application using the built-in Login capabilities, and it has been working well. 
 I would like to set DisplayRememberMe.visible to false depending on certain conditions (e.g. which Server, ip address, etc). Of course I can manually add `visible="false"` to the markup shown here, but that seems like a poor way to go.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" 
     CssClass="inline" >Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
```

Also, I can't figure out which asp field has the `DisplayRememberMe` field.

But more importantly, in the code behind file, I have added `LoginUser.DisplayRememberMe = False`, but it is ignored, and the label and checkbox are still visible. I have tried adding it to various events like Page.Load, Page.Init, Login_User.Init, Login_User.Prerender, but the checkbox and label are still visible after the page loads.

Am I using the proper call? Where should I place it to be effective?

This is my first post on SO, so please excuse any poor etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

You can change visibility of CheckBox  and  Label  by creating event of login control as
OnLoad="LoginUser_OnLoad"

On .cs page

```
 protected void LoginUser_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {            
            var login = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login)sender;
            var checkbox = login.FindControl("RememberMe");
            checkbox.Visible = false;
            var label = login.FindControl("RememberMeLabel");
            label.Visible = false;
        }
```

You can also put your visibility  conditions in LoginUser_OnLoad method.

Comment: Thanks Prashant. That definitely works, and solves my problem, but it does not address why changes to `LoginUser.DisplayRememberMe` do not work.